# Define navigation route for each element in a String List flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list of string which is a Text and each of this List should move me to a specific screen or action, at the momnent I am stuck into this issue, how to assign to each of the list a different route?
this is the code:

```
List<String> items = [
    'Spedizioni',
    'I Tuoi ordini',
    'Aggiungi un Prodotto',
    'Contattaci'
  ];
```

```
child: Row( 
          children: [
            Text(
              items[i],
              style: TextStyle(
                color: _isHovering[i]
                    ? Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button.decorationColor
                    : Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button.color,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 5,),
            Icon(icons[i]),
          ]
        ),
      );
```

and until here all ok because it show different item into the list but now I want each of this item in the list navigate to a route as now I defined just one, but I need to define different route for different item in the List

```
onTap: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AddingProductsPopup(),
          );
        },
```

Please help me to go out from this stuck

Comment: i understand ,just one question do you want to show dialogs when you click on item or navigate to another screen (root) because those are two deferent things ?

Comment: this list I posted is a menu
each of the item into the list should have an defined action, in the example I posted I called for an dialog but at the moment with this situation all the items into the menu move to the dialog.... I want the item into this menu to call/move to a different route or open dialog...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your full code  https://codeshare.io/an0jpv you can achieve that by like following :

```
     onTap: () {
      //here should have the options to call a different route for different List item menu

         // call for our alert dialog widget including one more variable which is  `items[i]` that has the text that would be passed to the alert
       onPressed: () {
           //here we show the pop up and pass the variable to it
              showAlert(context, items[i]);
              setState(() {});
            },
```

now let's define our alert widget

```
showAlert(BuildContext context, String myItem) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, setState) {
              return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("this is the clicked item $myItem",);});
            });
          );
        },
```

now when the popup shows and based on the received text from `items[i]` the dialog can have deferent titles , and you can add deferent conditions to adjust the content based on the text received from the press item;

Comment: if this help don't forget to mark as accepted , if it doesn't tell me what you want so i edit

Comment: I do not believe this is the right option because as you can see by the full code:
https://codeshare.io/an0jpv
I have different menu and just one TextWidget

Comment: hello I dont think the situation is clear please check my open issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64150877/assign-different-route-and-action-to-menu-list-in-flutter